# Definition of vcvtlsi2sd instruction

Tags: assembly, x86, avx

The v8 compiler emits `vcvtlsi2sd` if AVX is available, but I can't find that instruction in the Intel reference manual (or in any context outside of v8 when Googling). I gather it's an int to double conversion, but what is the `L` for?

Comment: Just assemble and disassemble in intel syntax. Or look at the machine code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `l` is almost certainly some non-standard syntax for 32-bit operand-size (for the integer source).

It's clearly a [`vcvtsi2sd xmm, xmm, r/m32`](https://github.com/HJLebbink/asm-dude/wiki/CVTSI2SD); there aren't any other instructions that would make sense, especially if int->double makes sense from context.  The same instruction works with 32 or 64-bit integer inputs, so it is meaningful to indicate operand-size.  The non-VEX SSE2 version is simply `cvtsi2sd xmm, r/m32`; I'd expect an `l` in the same place there unless V8 uses something completely different for the non-AVX case.

Operand-size is normally a suffix (b/w/l/q) in AT&T syntax, not stuffed into the middle of the mnemonic.  Does GAS assemble this syntax or is it just from V8's internal dump?  gcc doesn't put the operand-size override inside the mnemonic; it uses a `q` at the end if needed (when the operand-size isn't implied by a source register, i.e. with a memory source operand):

On the [Godbolt compiler explorer](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,source:'double+cvt32(int+*a)+%7B%0A++++return+*a%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Adouble+cvt64(long+long+*a)+%7B%0A++++return+*a%3B%0A%7D%0A'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:36.21710953893005,l:'4',m:100,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g73,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'1',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'1',trim:'1'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-O3+-mavx',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+gcc+7.3+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),k:33.333333333333336,l:'4',m:69.43556975505857,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:1,editor:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'%231+with+x86-64+gcc+7.3',t:'0')),header:(),l:'4',m:30.56443024494143,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),k:34.2809747522577,l:'3',n:'0',o:'',t:'0'),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang500,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'1',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'1',trim:'1'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-O3+-fverbose-asm+-Wall+-mavx',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+clang+5.0.0+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%232)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),header:(),l:'4',m:66.45367412140575,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:2,editor:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'%232+with+x86-64+clang+5.0.0',t:'0')),header:(),k:22.222222222222218,l:'4',m:33.54632587859425,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),k:29.50191570881226,l:'3',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4) with `gcc7.3 -O3 -mavx`:

```
double cvt32(int *a) {
    return *a;
}
    vxorpd  %xmm0, %xmm0, %xmm0
    vcvtsi2sd       (%rdi), %xmm0, %xmm0
    ret


double cvt64(long long *a) {
    return *a;
}
    vxorpd  %xmm0, %xmm0, %xmm0
    vcvtsi2sdq      (%rdi), %xmm0, %xmm0   # gcc7.3
    ret
```

Interestingly, clang uses `vcvtsi2sdl   (%rdi), %xmm0, %xmm0` for the 32-bit case; note the `l` suffix at the end of the instruction, not in the middle.

Comment: My `gas` (v2.22) certainly doesn't like it.

Comment: The [relevant part of the assembler source](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/master/src/x64/assembler-x64.h#L1502). It's clearly opcode `0x2a` which is in fact `vcvtsi2sd`.